# Ionic 2 and openpgp equals no errors but app does not bootup

Tags: ionic2, openpgp

I have a working ionic 2 app.  I wanted to add the openpgp library.  So I did a npm install and then added the typings.  Webpacks fine but now I get no errors, just a white screen.  If I comment out the

```
import * as openpgp from 'openpgp'
```

the app will boot up fine.  Since there are no errors generated during webpack nor at runtime in console I am at a loss at how to debug.

Comment: "then added the typings" did you add typings or @types package?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@types` from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).

`npm install --save openpgp`

Install @types:

`npm install --save-dev @types/openpgp`.

Make sure you have the following set in `compilerOptions` in your tsconfig.json

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
]
```

import as below:

```
import * as openpgp from 'openpgp'
```